# Winform Application UI Freeze while switching between other opened application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I've developed Windows Application using C# and .Net Framework 4.5

My application loads user control and takes input from users. There are probably more than 100 controls on that user control. It works fine when I am actively using my system.

Problem is when I keep my application open and toggle to other applications  which are also running e.g. checking my email, browse internet or using excel. After returning to my program, I can see the frame of my program and few controls but not all of them and I can see through my program to the last application which I visited. Also title bar of my app will become black.

**Please note that my app doesn't become inaccessible.** It's just won't load my all controls. I've assigned shortcut key to reload user control by which I can reload my user control and then it works fine.

[image: This is how freeze UI looks like]

[image: This is how it looks like when reload]

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your custom controls need some special drawing and this makes me think about the paint event.

Since you found a fix yourself

> I've assigned shortcut key to reload user control

I believe that you can use the `OnFocus` event to call this shortcut key or the code behind it.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your reply. I can't just keep on reloading my user control on every time user switch between as they might have feel up some data. However, I've already set timer of 3 minutes and if user re-visit my application after 3 minutes, I reload user control. But reloading every now and then is not good idea.

Comment: @Fredd indeed, refreshing the form is not the best idea, but unless you add some more code and detailed description about your application, I really doubt that somebody can understand why the controls are not displayed properly. Like what type of controls is not displayed well and things like that